# How to fix this Google+ sync problem?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sync, google-plus

Few months ago, I restored a full Nandroid backup which was created few hours ago. When I booted up, everything went fine, but Gmail & Google+ went out of sync. Perhaps, it was a timestamp problem.

Problem was this: If I read an email on web, the read status was reflected to app, but reverse wasn't true. If I read an email on app, the read status wasn't reflected to web or other devices/apps.
The exactly same thing was with Google+ notification read status.

I cleared data of Gmail app and the problem was fixed. I did the same thing with Google+ app, but no benefit. I even uninstalled & reinstalled the Google+ app, but again no benefit.

I left that for months. I have notified Google, updated to every new version, but the problem is still here even today.

How to fix it? Don't suggest factory reset, please.

Device: Samsung Galaxy S with ICS (rooted)

Answer (score 1):

You state you're running ICS on your Galaxy S so I assume it's CM9 or so and rooted.

Some thoughts of mine:

- Do you have any sort of firewall set up (e.g. droidwall)? That has bitten me often so far.
- Is there a 2nd device where it does not happen?
  Just trying to sort out a general problem with your account or G+
- Maybe G+ doesn't even sync by itself but *outsources* some of it to other GApps (or the Android framework)? Aka, the problem is not directly within the G+ app?

My steps to narrow it down would be:

1. Make a backup via CWM and be sure everything is backed up by Titanium Backup too. You want to be able to revert to this current state once all is debugged and the problem is found & fixed.
   Be sure your SD card has enough space left, I found CWM (v3.x) to not report that and *silently* fail in case of a *no space left on device* error.
2. Reboot into normal Android, remove unneeded apps and start a cycle:

   - clear app data of suspected problematic app (Google Services Framework, etc.)
   - test
   - retry and clear data of more apps and narrow down more if still present
3. If problem is found, revert to your backup, apply the fix and see if everything works fine still
4. Report your findings :-)

I know you don't wanted this answer but I include it nevertheless:
Wipe (with CWM and Titanium Backups ready of course). Then go partially back step by step (userland apps only) with TitaniumBackup. It's time consuming and tedious I know. Having a CWM backup ready leaves you the option to roll back at any time though.

Comment: I'll report my findings, but first I need plenty of time to do research.. Thanks!

Comment: If I have this kind of problem I usually take the last approach (wipe & revert only cherry picked packages from TiB) and just migrate old app data over that I definitely need. Usually 0.5-1h but if you are willing to dig and find the real cause you might need much more time

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have checked the sync options of your google+ account to make sure it is set to sync regularly.

Have you tried removing not ony the app but also the account from the phone, doing a restart and then adding the google account back again?

Comment: Account is primary which I can't remove without factory reset. I can do this with root, but its just removing credentials from database. I don't think it could help..